# Lucene query search in Alfresco gives strange result

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

I've two folders with the following values for *title*'s field : "passement" and "passage".

What I want is to only get the first folder, I'm using then the following query to search it :

```
@projectName\:title:"*passement*"
```

The current result gives the two folders, why ?

I'm using Alfresco 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your term/phrase are tokenized before the search.
You should use '=' to search for an exact term.
e.g.

```
=projectName\:title:"*passement*"
```

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-exact.html

Tested on localhost:

```
@cm:name:"*Reporter*"
```

> Found over 100 results
>   ...
>   Business Trip report #1,2,3...
>   ...
>   Test report_Adnvin
>   ...

```
=cm:name:"*Reporter*"
```

> Found 3 results
>   Business Trip Reporter
>   Test Reporter folder
>   Reporter 1

Comment: Tested that, it returned nothing.. The sign "=" seems to be unknown because this is only valid for FTS.

Comment: “When we added Solr to Alfresco 4, we deprecated Lucene.” (c) Richard Esplin. Maybe you should use alfresco fts?

If you don't want to do this, just remove double quotes from the value.

Comment: It worked fine after removing the double quotes. Thank you @mrgrechkinn.

Comment: Though, searching the first folder's _title_ Upper-cased becomes no longer possible, e.g. "PASSEMENT" gives nothing. Any idea ?

Comment: I have tested the same "=" sign in node browser but it does not return anything.